# Sort SQL based on two fields and extra constraint

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am attempting to write an SQLite Query that orders a table `mytable` firstly by a column called `status_id` and secondly by a column called `name`, but with an extra constraint using:

```
SELECT name, 
       status_id 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY status_id, name
```

produces a table that is correctly sorted.

e.g (name, status): ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 2), ("b", 3), ("a", 4)...

However I require the same sort of output, but with any result having `status_id` equal to 2, being at the top of the results.

e.g. ("a", 2), ("c", 2), ("b", 1), ("b", 3), ("a", 4)...

---

I came up with this, but it doesn't function as required as the list isn't also subsorted by name:

```
SELECT name, 
       status_id 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY CASE status_id 
WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
```

Comment: +1 You showed us what have you tired so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to sort by status_id and name, AFTER you sort by the CASE statement.

```
SELECT  name
        , status_id 
FROM    mytable 
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN status_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
        ,status_id
        ,name
```

Comment: Ah so close! Makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

Just sort the rest by `status_id` and add `name` yo your `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT name, status_id 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY CASE status_id 
         WHEN 2 THEN -1 
         ELSE status_id 
         END,
         name
```

Answer (score 2):

Just also add `status_id, name` at the end:

```
SELECT name, status_id FROM mytable 
ORDER BY CASE status_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, status_id, name
```